# $\sup_{x\in A}x \sup_{y\in B}y=\sup_{x\in A,y\in B}xy$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets of nonnegtive numbers. Prove that

> $\sup_{x\in A}x \sup_{y\in B}y=\sup_{x\in A,y\in B}xy$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I find your notation odd. Generally one writes sup A where A is a set - maybe that's the source of your confusion. Consider the set $C=\{xy:x\in A,y\in B\}$. What can be said about sup C?

Comment: @Zen : It looks odd at first, but notations of the form 
$$
\sup_{x \in A} f(x)
$$
are very standard in analysis. Look at it as 
$$
\sup_{x \in A} f(x) = \sup\{ f(x) \, | \, x \in A \}.
$$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense for a set f(A) but $\sup_{x\in A}x$ doesn't make sense because x is not a set.

Comment: This really seems like the kind of question that you should answer yourself, especially considering that (as I see from one of your other questions on this site) you are a 3rd or 4th year PhD student.

Comment: @Zen I don't understand your objection.  $f(x)$ is not a set either.  Nevertheless, the notation Patrick has defined is common and unambiguous.

Comment: Have you tried searching the site?

Comment: Not really an objection :) I don't have anything against Patrick's notation, I just thought the OP's notation was a bit unusual. f(x) is not a set but it is understood to refer to f(A), which is pointless for $f(x)=x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x \in A$, then $x \le \sup A$. Similarly, $y \le \sup B$. Since $x,y \ge 0$, we have $xy \le \sup A \sup B$. It follows that $\sup_{x \in A, y \in B} x y \le \sup A \sup B$.

In the other direction, if $x \in A, y \in B$, then $xy \le \sup_{x' \in A, y' \in B} x' y'$. Then $\sup_{y \in B} x y = x \sup B \le \sup_{x' \in A, y' \in B} x' y'$. Since this is true for all $x \in A$, and both $x\ge0$ and $\sup B \ge 0$, we have $\sup_{x \in A} x \sup B =\sup A \sup B \le\sup_{x' \in A, y' \in B} x' y'$.

Comment: How do you know that $\sup_{y \in B} xy \le \sup_{x' \in A , y' \in B} x'y'$?

Comment: Since $xy \le \text{right hand side}$ for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, it must be true when we take the $\sup$ over $B$. (If taking the $\sup$ reversed the inequality, then for some $y \in B$ you would have $x y > \text{right hand side}$.)

Comment: What if the $\sup$ isn't achieved? Then $\sup B \not\in B$ and that inequality is invalid

Comment: The $\sup$ doesn't have to be a member of the set. You have $xy \le \text{right hand side}$. Suppose $\sup_{y \in B} x y > \text{right hand side}$, then for all $\epsilon>0$, you can find some $y \in B$ such that $xy \ge \sup_{y \in B} x y -\epsilon$. By choosing $\epsilon>0$ suitably small, you get a contradiction. Hence the desired inequality.

Comment: I might still be being silly but I don't see how that's a contradiction - what are you contradicting?

Comment: You have, for all $x \in A, y \in B$ that $x y \le \text{right hand side}$ above. Your question was why $\sup_{y \in B} xy \le \text{right hand side}$. My comments were just showing that if $\sup_{y \in B} xy > \text{right hand side}$, then it must be true for some $y \in B$, that is, $xy > \text{right hand side}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: so then you're assuming that $\exists \; \epsilon > 0 : \sup_{y \in B} xy - \epsilon < rhs$. How do you know that?

Comment: (Remember $x \ge 0$. If $x=0$ there is nothing to show, so suppose $x>0$.) If $\alpha = \sup_{y \in B} x$, then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $y \in B$ such that $x y > \alpha - \epsilon$. This is from the definition of $\sup.

Comment: It still seems like you're making a pretty hefty assumption - just because $\sup_{y \in B} xy > \sup_{x' \in A , y' \in B} x'y'$ doesn't mean $\exists \; y \in B : xy > \sup_{x' \in A , y' \in B} x'y'$

Comment: Dan, there's no assumption there. This is just the definition of $\sup$.

Comment: Are you in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9068/discussion-between-copper-hat-and-danzimm)

Answer (score 3):

This may help:

For each real number $M $:
$$\sup_{x\in A}x \sup_{y\in B}y\le M$$
$$\leftrightarrow (\forall x\in A)(x \sup_{y\in B}y\le M)$$
$$\leftrightarrow (\forall x\in A)(\forall y\in B)(xy\le M)$$
$$\leftrightarrow (\forall (x,y)\in A\times B)(xy\le M)$$
$$\leftrightarrow \sup_{(x,y)\in A\times B} xy\le M$$

Now try 
$$M=\sup_{x\in A}x \sup_{y\in B}y$$
and
$$M=\sup_{(x,y)\in A\times B} xy$$

---

> - if $a\ge 0$ and for each $x\in A$, $f(x)\in \Bbb R$ then we have:
>     $$(\forall x\in A)( af(x)\le M)\leftrightarrow a\sup_{x\in A} f(x)\le M$$

Comment: I assume that those $\Bbb R$s were force of habit?

Comment: It may help if you pointed out where you used the non-negativity of $x,y$.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: I realize that. I was suggesting that you mention that in your proof.

Comment: I want this answer be deleted.